# How can piece together Edge Detection Result and Original Picture in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to perform edge detection in a picture using the `Canny`.

Then, I want to reverse the colors of the detected edges (black edge on white background).

Finally, I need to compose the original picture and edges into one image.

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
picture = cv2.imread("picture.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(picture,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edge = cv2.Canny(gray,100,250,3)
(thresh, blackEdges) = cv2.threshold(edge, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
result = blackEdges + gray   # I tryed this and ,i didn't get what i want.
cv2.imshow("Result",result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `picture[blackEdges==0] = (0,0,0)` will make your picture black where the edge image is black. You can replace (0,0,0) with (0,0,255) to make them show as red. Likewise for any other color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your result line with

```
result = picture.copy()
result[blackEdges==0] = (0,0,0)
```

That will make your picture black where the edge image is black. You can replace (0,0,0) with (0,0,255) to make them show as red. Likewise for any other color.

If you want the edges on the gray image, then do

```
result = gray.copy()
result[blackEdges==0] = (0,0,0)
```

Comment: You do not actually need `blackEdges`. You can used `edge == 255`, instead.

Comment: @fmw42 and #Amitai Irron  thanks a lot  , it worked .